# return a list of tuples from database records with python and postgresql

Tags: python, database, postgresql, tuples

Hello I'm having a hard time trying to make this function in which I have to:

```
"""Returns a list of the players and their win records, sorted by wins.

The first entry in the list should be the player in first place, or a player
tied for first place if there is currently a tie.

Returns:
  A list of tuples, each of which contains (id, name, wins, matches):
    id: the player's unique id (assigned by the database)
    name: the player's full name (as registered)
    wins: the number of matches the player has won
    matches: the number of matches the player has played
"""
```

currently I have this function to try solve that:

```
def playerStandings():
    conn = connect()
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT id, name \
            FROM players LEFT JOIN matches \
            ON players.id = matches.id_winner \
            ORDER BY players.id")
    result = c.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return result
```

and when I run the code I get this error msg:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "tournament_test.py", line
>   152, in 
>       testStandingsBeforeMatches()   File "tournament_test.py", line 61, in testStandingsBeforeMatches
>       raise ValueError("Each playerStandings row should have four columns.") ValueError: Each playerStandings row should have four
>   columns.

line 152 in tournament_test.py is:

```
testStandingsBeforeMatches()
```

and line 61 is:

```
if len(standings[0]) != 4:
    raise ValueError("Each playerStandings row should have four columns.")
[(id1, name1, wins1, matches1), (id2, name2, wins2, matches2)] = standings
```

and finally variable "standings" is a call to my function playerStandings() in line 54

```
standings = playerStandings()
```

this is my sql script to create the database and the tables:

```
CREATE DATABASE tournament;
\c tournament;
CREATE TABLE players (id SERIAL, name TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (id)); 
CREATE TABLE matches (
    id_match SERIAL, 
    id_winner SERIAL REFERENCES players(id),
    id_looser SERIAL REFERENCES players(id),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_match)
);
```

what can I do to solve this? I'm really new with python so I don't understand it very well

Comment: Are you connecting to the database with the same user that you used to create that tables with? What you seem to be running into is a permissions error, connecting user that you used to create the tables with would verify if it is or not.

Comment: hi @John I edited the post with the correct error please check it again

Comment: The dict have 4 items in each tuple, but the query result only have tow columns each row, that's the code raise error.

Comment: can you help me fix it @KevinYan please

Comment: what you want is can not get by one sql,  you now have id and name, and the next you need to  iterate the result , and use each rows id in another two `sqls` to which get associated wins and matches .

Comment: I still don't get it.. could you please make the sqls sentences to accomplish that? @KevinYan

Answer (score 0):

I don't use `postgresql`, the code may not use in your routine directly, so you need modify on this basis to let it work. I just give you some hints to let you know how to fix the problem.

```
def playerStandings():
     conn = connect()
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT id, name \
            FROM players LEFT JOIN matches \
            ON players.id = matches.id_winner \
            ORDER BY players.id")
    result = c.fetchall()#get all id and name, I don't know the type of result, assume its a list of dicts.

    for row in result:
        #sql to get wins
        c.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) AS wins FROM WHERE id_winner = row['id']");
        win_data = c.fetch()
        row['wins'] = win_data['wins']
        #sql to get matches
        c.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) AS matches FROM WHERE id_winner = row['id']" OR id_looser = row['id'])
        match_data = c.fetch()
        row['matches'] = match_data['matches']

    conn.close()
    return result
```